# Setting the formulas of a range equal to the formulas of another range

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to consolidate the contents of a template populated by a large group of users.

When consolidating the data, I originally copied and pasted it using Paste formulas. This did not work as the pasted formulas referenced their source workbook (e.g. "='[Workbook1.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1" instead of "Sheet1'!A1").

I'm now attempting to set the formulas of a range in the consolidated workbook (which I call "target") equal to the formulas of a range (same dimensions) in the source workbook.

This works when the coordinates of the two ranges are equal.
When they are not equal (but equal in size), it does not work and throws an error. For example:

```vb
Target.Range(Cells(1,1).address,Cells(1,10).address).formula = Source.Range(cells(1,1).address,Cells(1,10).address).formula    ' ---> No issues
```

```vb
Target.Range(Cells(2,1).address,Cells(2,10).address).formula = Source.Range(cells(1,1).address,Cells(1,10).address).formula    ' ---> Error
```

Complete code of the function. Note that it returns a double to record the next empty row in the target workbook:

```vb
Public Function copy_formulas(ByVal source As Worksheet, source_row As Integer, _ 
    source_start_col As Integer, data_width As Integer, ByVal target As Worksheet, target_start_row _
    As Integer, target_start_col As Integer) As Double
    
    'Copy the **FORMULAS** of the source worksheet row by row until the lead column of the source table is blank
    
    Do While source.Cells(source_row, source_start_col) <> ""
    
        target.Range(Cells(target_start_row, target_start_col).Address, Cells(target_start_row, _
        target_start_col + data_width).Address).Formula = source.Range(Cells(source_row, _
        source_start_col).Address, Cells(source_row, source_start_col + data_width).Address).Formula
    
        'Increment both source and target row counters
    
        source_row = source_row + 1
        target_start_row = target_start_row + 1
    
    Loop
    
    copy_formulas = target_start_row
    
End Function
```

Error:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Formulas:

Ex 1: (This formula is my method of getting around the inability to use merged cells in Excel tables. Each Risk can have multiple associated mitigating actions. This formula pulls all the details of all the mitigating actions from Table4 which belong to a corresponding entry of the Risk registry table where each row represents a different risk.)

```
={IFERROR(LEFT(CONCAT(IF(Table4[@[Risk ID]]=[@[Risk ID]],"-"&Table4[@[Mitigating Action ID]]&" ","")),LEN(CONCAT(IF(Table4[@[Risk ID]]=[@[Risk ID]],"-"&Table4[@[Mitigating Action ID]]&" ","")))-1),"")}
```

Ex 2:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Likelihood ]],Table6,4,FALSE)*VLOOKUP([@[Severity ]],Table6,4,FALSE),"")
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that all my formulas use named ranges which exist in both workbooks (e.g. table1). Thanks!

Comment: What are the formulae you're moving across? I can't recreate the issue with a formula that sums a few numbers in a namedrange.

Comment: "throws an error" could be a little more explicit - what error does it throw?

Comment: Error:

"Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

Formulas:
Ex 1: "     ={IFERROR(LEFT(CONCAT(IF(Table4[@[Risk ID]]=[@[Risk ID]],"-"&Table4[@[Mitigating Action ID]]&"
","")),LEN(CONCAT(IF(Table4[@[Risk ID]]=[@[Risk ID]],"-"&Table4[@[Mitigating Action ID]]&"
","")))-1),"")}      "
Ex 2: "     =IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Likelihood ]],Table6,4,FALSE)*VLOOKUP([@[Severity ]],Table6,4,FALSE),"")     "
                            Also, how do I save the new line inserts in stack overflow comments? I'm using shift+enter but its not saving.

Comment: If you need to add code or information, it's best to edit your question and add it there: as you're finding out it's difficult to make it readable in a comment.

Comment: Edited the question to include the details of my above comment as suggested by @TimWilliams. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by using a one dimensional variant array to temporarily hold the formulas of the source cells. Basically instead of attempting:

target.range().formulas = source.range().formulas

I used two steps:

formula_holder() = source.range().formulas
target.range().formulas = formula_holder()

Actual working function:

```
Public Function copy_formulas(ByVal source As Worksheet, source_row As Integer, source_start_col As Integer, data_width As Integer, ByVal target As Worksheet, target_start_row As Integer, target_start_col As Integer) As Double

'Dim variant array to store source formulas and position counter
Dim formula_holder() As Variant
ReDim formula_holder(data_width)
Dim i As Integer


'Copy the **FORMULAS** of the source worksheet row by row until the lead column of the source table is blank

Do While source.Cells(source_row, source_start_col) <> ""
    
    i = 0

    For Each cell In source.Range(Cells(source_row, source_start_col).Address, Cells(source_row, source_start_col + data_width).Address)
            
            formula_holder(i) = CStr(cell.Formula)
            i = i + 1
            
    Next cell
    
    i = 0
    
    For Each cell In target.Range(Cells(target_start_row, target_start_col).Address, Cells(target_start_row, target_start_col + data_width).Address)
            
            cell.Formula = formula_holder(i)
            i = i + 1
            
    Next cell

'target.Range(Cells(target_start_row, target_start_col).Address, Cells(target_start_row, target_start_col + data_width).Address).Formula = source.Range(Cells(source_row, source_start_col).Address, Cells(source_row, source_start_col + data_width).Address).Formula

'Increment both source and target row counters

source_row = source_row + 1
target_start_row = target_start_row + 1

Loop

copy_formulas = target_start_row

End Function
```